# event function can't call two or more other functions at the same time

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I made a sample form validation using only plain javascript. Everything was ok until I decided to store the two functions inside an event callback function. I did it so my javascript file can only have lesser lines of code. The callback function can only execute one function.

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function isBlank(element) {
  var isblank = (!element.value) ? true : false;

  element.setAttribute('data-error', isblank);

  return isblank;
}

function isInvalid(element, regex) {
  var invalidValue = (!element.value.match(regex)) ? true : false;

  element.setAttribute('data-error', invalidValue);

  return invalidValue;
}

function checkInput(e) {
  var $this = e.target;
  return [
    isBlank($this),
    isInvalid($this, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/)
  ];
}

query('#name').addEventListener('blur', checkInput);
```

```css
form input[name] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

form input[data-error="true"] {
  border-color: red;
}

form input[data-error="false"] {
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" data-error=""><span class="message"></span><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I also tried the following two options, but it didn't work either:

```
function checkInput(e) {
  var $this = e.target;
  return {
    execute: [
      isBlank($this),
      isInvalid($this, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/)
    ]
  };
}

function checkInput(e) {
  var $this = e.target;
  isBlank($this);
  isInvalid($this, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/);
}
```

How can I fix it but make the code cleaner and more organized?

Comment: You use same data-error attribute. So the 2nd one will override it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function isBlank(element) {
  var isblank = (!element.value) ? true : false;

  return isblank;
}

function isInvalid(element, regex) {
  var invalidValue = (!element.value.match(regex)) ? true : false;

  return invalidValue;
}

function checkInput(e) {
  var $this = e.target;
  element.setAttribute('data-error', (isBlank($this) || isInvalid($this, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/)));
}

query('#name').addEventListener('blur', checkInput);
```

It will set 'data-error' to true if at least one of the functions returns true (and has found an error)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running ok. I changed attributes name to see if they are added and they are. The problem is that you use the same data-error attribute and 2nd function overrides first. May be you should just add and remove class that represents the error. Than you can have so much errors you want.

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function isBlank(element) {
  var isblank = (!element.value) ? true : false;

  element.setAttribute('data-error1', isblank);

  return isblank;
}

function isInvalid(element, regex) {
  var invalidValue = (!element.value.match(regex)) ? true : false;

  element.setAttribute('data-error2', invalidValue);

  return invalidValue;
}

function checkInput(e) {
  var $this = e.target;
  return [
    isBlank($this),
    isInvalid($this, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/)
  ];
}

query('#name').addEventListener('blur', checkInput);
```

```css
form input[name] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

form input[data-error="true"] {
  border-color: red;
}

form input[data-error="false"] {
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" data-error=""><span class="message"></span><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The `border-color` should turn red if it's blank or has wrong regex

Comment: Sure it is not working. Just read the answer. I changed the attribute names to demonstrate that they both applied and offer another approach.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like this.

I would recommend setting the `element.attribute` outside of `isBlank` and `isInvalid`. Now you could use those functions in other contexts.

And when you want the source element of an event handler I would use `this` instead of `event.target`. It solves some problems with nested elements.

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function isBlank(element) {
  return (!element.value) ? true : false;
}

function isInvalid(element, regex) {
  return (!element.value.match(regex)) ? true : false;
}

function checkInput(e) {
  var isValid = true;
  
  if(isBlank(this) || isInvalid(this, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/)){
    isValid = false;
  }
  
  this.setAttribute('data-error', !isValid);
}

query('#name').addEventListener('blur', checkInput);
```

```css
form input[name] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

form input[data-error="true"] {
  border-color: red;
}

form input[data-error="false"] {
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" data-error=""><span class="message"></span><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful